# Using "defer" in this way?

Tags: word-usage

I wonder if "defer" can be used in such a way: "We defer this discussion to the last section (of this paper)", for example. My hesitation came from that search results did not give similar usage.

Comment: Can you clarify what machining are you trying to convey?

Comment: @rpeinhardt, Hi. I intended to make it open as I was not sure if a certain example would distort the result I wanted. But, it seems that your question is frequent here. I made it specific now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Defer is acceptable in this instance but with a different preposition

You are leaving the argument until later in the paper and "defer" means to put off until later.

However, you would use the preposition "until" for this use of defer. You use "to" when you're using defer's other meaning.

> **I defer the argument until later.** (Put off)

Versus

> **I defer to his wisdom** (submit/yield)

Comment: You meant to type "preposition", I think.  **Defer *to*** {a later time} is grammatical but is somewhat dated, being used much more often in the 19th and 18th centuries than it is today. But in formal and "donnish" writing it is still encountered.

Comment: @rpeinhardt, Thank you for expanding the nuances; those are helpful..

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, Thank you for the supplemental info. By the way, "donnish" is a word I needed and now it popped up due to something else. Thanks I mean.